# Implementation of sinus function | Calculation Time

Tags: java

Can anybody tell me why this code doesn't work? I'm trying to implement a sinus-function with a given limitation of precision (by the error-variable).

Certain details about the calculation are given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

berechnePot calculates the potence
berechneFak calculates the faculty
berechneVZW calculates the pre sign (plus or minus)

[image]

I don't get the point, why the function is calculating that slow.

```
public class Sinus {

    public static double sinus(double x) {
        double error = 0.001;

        double summand = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        int k = 0;
        do {
            double pot = 0;
            double fak = 0;
            pot = berechnePot(x, k);
            fak = berechneFak(k);
            summand = pot / fak;
            berechneVZW(summand, k);
            sum += summand;

            k++;
        } while (abs(summand) > error);
        return sum;
    }

    public static double abs(double value) {
        if (value < 0) return -value;
        else return value;
    }

    public static double berechneVZW(double value, int k) {
        if (k % 2 == 0) {
            return value;
        } else {
            return value *= (-1);
        }
    }

    public static double berechnePot(double x, double k) {
        double pot = 0;
        pot += x;
        for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
            pot *= (x * x);
        }
        return pot;
    }

    public static double berechneFak(int k) {
        double fak = 1;
        if (k == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i <= k; k++) {
                fak *= (2 * i + 1);
            }
        }
        return fak;

    }
}
```

Finally i got to the right solution..

I hope that the new structure helps you to better understand my implementation better.

Thanks for all your help!

```
public class Sinus {

public static double sinus(double x) {
    double error = 0.00001;

    double summand = 0;
    double result = 0;
    double fak = 0;

    int k = 0;
    do {
        double pot = 0;
        pot = calcNumeratorPotency(x, k);
        fak = calcDenumeratorFaculty(k);
        summand = pot / fak;
        summand = definePreSign(summand, k);
        result += summand;
        k++;
    } while (absoluteValue(summand) > error);
    return result;
}

public static double absoluteValue(double value) {
    if (value < 0)
        return -value;
    else
        return value;
}

public static double definePreSign(double value, int k) {
    if (k % 2 == 0) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return value * (-1);
    }
}

public static double calcNumeratorPotency(double x, double k) {
    double pot = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * k; i++) {
        pot *= x;
    }
    return pot;
}

public static double calcDenumeratorFaculty(int k) {
    double fak = 1;
    if (k == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= (2 * k + 1); i++) {
            fak *= i;
        }
    }
    return fak;

}
```

Comment: Is this an assignment, or why do you implement an existing method, which is part of the Math-Utility-class? Same for abs

public static double Math.sin(double rad) ...

public static double Math.abs(double val) ...

Comment: You ignore the result of `berechneVZW(summand, k);`. And inside `berechneVZW(double value, int k)` the `=` in the last `return` statement is unnecessary since you just return the value.

Comment: @TreffnonX : I'm just preparing myself through some own practices and I just want to understand some more..

Comment: Without diving into the math, the `berechneFak()` function is the slowest one in my test.

Comment: @sezi80 Thanks for your response, but it doesn't consider the fact, that the program while it's executed calculats really slow. I don't get the point why it needs that much time? Which operations are consuming the most time? 

Secondly the resulting value doesn't look like it's right. Can you confirm that it's implemented well?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have worked with another language before. Java works a bit different than you seem to expect.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= k; k++) {
    fak *= (2 * i + 1);
}
```

This particular loop is definetly not working as expected. You increment `k`, but `i`is supposed to grow? Might be you want to write:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
    fak *= (2 * i + 1);
}
```

Because the loop counts `k`, instead of `i`, it continues, until k overruns the integer-range and becomes `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. At that point, your loop finally terminates. :)

On a completely different note, and meant as constructive critique: You might want to take a look at the default Java-Style-Guide (https://github.com/twitter/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/styleguide.md)

Small excerpt:

```
// Bad.
//   - This offers poor visual separation of operations.
int foo=a+b+1;

// Good.
int foo = a + b + 1;
```

Spaces between identifiers and operators are very, very helpful, operating with numbers, but also with a lot of different stuff.

Answer (score 2):

It is not quite clear to me what you are calculating in `berechnePot` and `berechnePot`. They seem to be the numerators and denominators, judging from the context.

Running your code with a debugger, I can see that `summand` is calculated very wrongly, and decreases very slowly. This is the reason why it takes so long.

The `Math` class provides a `pow` method, so you don't really need to use a for loop to calculate powers. I think you might be overcomplicating this a bit. I would write a `getSummand` method and a `factorial` method:

```
private static double getSummand(double x, int k) {
    int power = k * 2 + 1;
    double numerator = Math.pow(x, power);
    double denominator = factorial(power);
    int sign = k % 2 == 1 ? -1 : 1;
    return numerator / denominator * sign;
}

private static double factorial(int x) {
    double result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And use them like this:

```
public static double sinus(double x) {
    double error = 0.001;

    double summand = 0;
    double sum = 0;

    int k = 0;
    do {
        summand = getSummand(x, k);
        sum += summand;

        k++;
    } while (Math.abs(summand) > error);
    return sum;
}
```

If this is an assignment and you are not allowed to use anything from the `Math` class, you could write your own `pow` method like this:

```
private static double pow(double x, int p) {
    double result = 1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < p ; i++) {
        result *= x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `berechneFak()` function you have a loop inside the `else` clause. You do increment `k` but not `i` so `i <= k` is always true. Try looking at it in a debugger. This is the loop that is slowing it down.

So every time `k` will count up to the max integer value of 2,147,483,647 in single increments and then overflow to a negative value at which point the loop will end.

Just to clarify: I did not look at if the math is correct but just at why the program is slow.